# How to Submit Form after Modal fadeOut?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I try to make my form submitted after the modal has finished `fading out`, then to submit the form to mail to `refreshform.php` the email file is ready,
but after the modal has faded out the form does not submit or post something to php file so send it to email , its just fade out and did not submit

this is my files 
thank you for your help !

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#questionWrapper .question').first().show(); //show first questionblock
  
  $("#questionWrapper .answer" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.question').hide();
    if ($(this).parent().next('.question').length) {
        $(this).parent().next('.question').fadeIn();
    } else {
        startCheck();
    }
  });
});

function startCheck() {

var overlay = $('.overlay-checker'),
    points = $('.overlay-checker-points > li');

// Initially, hide all the points so we can show them one by one
points.hide();

// Fade in the overlay
overlay.fadeIn();

// Loop points.lenght times (so through every point)
for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.overlay-checker-points').find(':hidden').first().fadeIn();
  }, 1500 * (i + 1));
}

// After all items have been faded in, redirect
setTimeout(function () {
          ('.overlay-checker').fadeOut('500', function(
           $('form').submit();) {
   
});
    
    
}, 1500 * points.length + 2000);

}

function toggleDiv(target) {
  $(target).toggle();
}
```

```css
    .countWrapper {
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    .rulesBox {
        width: 80%; background-color: #ffffff; margin: 10px 0 15px 0; padding: 20px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }

    .centerIt {
        margin:0px auto;
        text-align:center;
        margin-top: 125px;
    }
    .centerIt a {
        margin:0px auto;
    }

    .overlay-checker {
        display: none;
        background: #fff;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    .overlay-checker {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 35px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .overlay-checker-points {
        max-width: 700px;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .overlay-checker-points li{list-style: none;}
    .overlay-checker-points li img{height: 21px;}
```

```html
<form class="form" method="post" id="form"  action="refreshform.php">
      
      <p class="name">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
      </p>
      
      <p class="email">
        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
      </p>
        
        <p class="country">
        <input name="country" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Country" id="country" />
      </p>
        <p class="apps">to ensure your not a bot <strong>you must download 2 FREE Apps</strong> and only after the GiftCard will be Sent.</p>
      
      
      
      
      <div class="kapot">
        <input type="button" name="go" onclick="startCheck()" id="submit" value="Go"/>
        <div class="ease"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: there is a syntax error in your snippet - also in your "real" code?

Comment: yes there is and i dont know where is the error its just popup after i added the form submit part @messerbill
this is all my js file

Comment: this is all my js file

Comment: `// After all items have been faded in, redirect
setTimeout(function () {
          $('.overlay-checker').fadeOut('500', function() {
   $('form').submit();
});` Corrected syntax

Comment: @Rikin `('.overlay-checker').fadeOut('` must be `$('.overlay-checker').fadeOut('` - this is why `unexpected token (` occurs

Comment: Yeah I actually focused on the syntax error only. Was in fact missing `$` sign

Comment: i did not understand how to fix the error i added $ and there is still Syntax error saying setTimeout is not defined @messerbil

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error here:

```
// After all items have been faded in, redirect
setTimeout(function () {
          ('.overlay-checker').fadeOut('500', function(
           $('form').submit();) {

});
```

Also another syntax here with `'.overlay-checker'`

I corrected those below...

**EDIT: I also removed the ID of your button from being called `id="submit"` because that seems to be creating a conflict for submitting the form.

NB: as the overlay markup is not in this example, I added a condition to submit otherwise.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#questionWrapper .question').first().show(); //show first questionblock
  
  $("#questionWrapper .answer" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.question').hide();
    if ($(this).parent().next('.question').length) {
        $(this).parent().next('.question').fadeIn();
    } else {
        startCheck();
    }
  });
});

function startCheck() {

var overlay = $('.overlay-checker'),
    points = $('.overlay-checker-points > li');

// Initially, hide all the points so we can show them one by one
points.hide();

// Fade in the overlay
overlay.fadeIn();

// Loop points.lenght times (so through every point)
for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.overlay-checker-points').find(':hidden').first().fadeIn();
  }, 1500 * (i + 1));
}

// After all items have been faded in, redirect
setTimeout(function () {
 console.log('Timer started.');
 
 if(jQuery('.overlay-checker').length){
 jQuery('.overlay-checker').fadeOut('500', function() {
   
   console.log('Fade out complete. Submitting form.');
   jQuery('#form').submit();
   
 });
 }else{
 
   console.log('Fade selector not found. Submitting form immediately.');
   jQuery('#form').submit();
   
 }
   
}, 1500 * points.length + 2000);

}

function toggleDiv(target) {
  $(target).toggle();
}
```

```css
.countWrapper {
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    .rulesBox {
        width: 80%; background-color: #ffffff; margin: 10px 0 15px 0; padding: 20px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }

    .centerIt {
        margin:0px auto;
        text-align:center;
        margin-top: 125px;
    }
    .centerIt a {
        margin:0px auto;
    }

    .overlay-checker {
        display: none;
        background: #fff;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    .overlay-checker {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 35px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .overlay-checker-points {
        max-width: 700px;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .overlay-checker-points li{list-style: none;}
    .overlay-checker-points li img{height: 21px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="form" method="post" id="form"  action="refreshform.php">

      
      <p class="name">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
      </p>
      
      <p class="email">
        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
      </p>
        
        <p class="country">
        <input name="country" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Country" id="country" />
      </p>
        <p class="apps">to ensure your not a bot <strong>you must download 2 FREE Apps</strong> and only after the GiftCard will be Sent.</p>
      
      
      
      
      <div class="kapot">
        <input type="button" name="go" onclick="startCheck()" value="Go"/>
        <div class="ease"></div>
      </div>
      
    </form>
```

Comment: im sorry for my bad english but i want after the model is faded out the form that the user submited to be sent to my Email , and its just fade out and stop and dont get to form action the file called refreshform.php and i added that on my form

Comment: Ok, I made an edit. The ID attribute for the button seemed to have a conflict. I removed it and the script seems to submit now.